# Finding Variance of max choosing two prime numbers

Tags: probability

> a) two numbers are chosen from n first *prime* numbers (repetitions are allowed). If the first is X and the second is Y, find the distribution and variance of  $M=max(X,Y)$
>
> b)assume now we choose r of n  *prime* numbers where $X_1..X_r$ are the chosen numbers (M now is the $\max({X_1...X_r})$). Find variance of M.
>
> c) Find the distribution of $S=sec(X_1..X_r)$, the second maximum (a.k.a the maximum after rejecting the maximum of X).

About A: I found the distribution of (X,Y) which is given by $P(X=n_1,Y=n_2)=\frac{1}{n_1\cdot n_2}$. Can I say that $P(M=k)=\begin{cases}
n_1, & \text{if } n_1>n_2 \text{} \\
n_2, & \text{if } n1\le n_2
\end{cases}$
With probabilty $\frac 1 2$ for each option? and then $\mathbb E[M]=\frac{n_1+n_2}{2},\mathbb E[M]=\frac{n_1+n_2}{4}$ and $Var(M)=\frac{n_1+n_2}{4}$?

About B,C: I have no good idea either with how to manage with choosing max from r of n or how to find the distribution of $S=sec(X_1..X_r)$.

Is my answer for A is correct? Can I be given a hint about how to solve B and C?

Comment: When you have decided whether these numbers have to be prime or not, please let us know :-)

Comment: they are all primes. Where did i write other statements?

Comment: You don't mention prime numbers at all in the body of the question!  Surely you can see that this is ambiguous?

Comment: I edited the question(added 'prime' in the right places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the $n$ prime numbers by $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_n$. For each $k$, $M=p_k$ means that either $X=p_k$ and $Y=p_i$ with $i\lt p$, or $X=Y=p_k$, or $X=p_i$ and $Y=p_k$ with $i\lt k$.

Hence, for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$,
$$
P[M=p_k]=\frac{2k-1}{n^2}.
$$
The other questions can be treated similarly.